# Not receiving Apex exception emails

Tags: apex, email, exception

I am unable to receive any Apex exception emails in both my own dev playground org and the sandboxes/production org for the company I work for. I remember at my last company I would receive exception emails quite regularly however now I am not receiving any at all.

In my dev org I am trying to test what I need to do to receive these emails. I have tried creating code to error out however I still am not receiving any emails for these. My email devliverability settings are set to "All Email", I have added my email to the Apex Exception Email settings, and I am the last modified user on the code I am running. I also have "Send Apex Warning Emails" checked on my user record, and I do recieve warnings for getting near governor limits. I have ran the "test send emails" functionality through Salesforce to make sure my email is receiving Salesforce emails and I did receive all 30-something of them.

I have written a trigger on the account that runs too many SOQL queries. In the UI it gives me the error, but no email is sent. I have created code on this trigger to grab a record type by name with a name that doesn't exist, it returns a null error in the UI but no email. I have created a Visualforce Page that has a controller which tries to reference a null object, the page returns the message "Attempt to de-reference a null object 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.", but no email is sent. I have created a button on this visualforce page that calls a future method that returns a null exception, and the job itself says it failed due to a null error, but no email is sent.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong and why I am not receiving any error emails for unhandled exceptions. Is there something I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Does anyone else receive the emails if you add them to Apex Exception Emails?  What if you try a different email for yourself like a gmail addr?

Comment: Hi David- thanks for your reply. I have tried using both my personal Gmail addresses and my official work address. We are receiving some error emails- the other day we got a System.NullPointerException email from an AfterInsert trigger. I just do not understand why they are sending in some cases an not others. In my developer org I am having the same issue, so I am wondering exactly what the criteria is for triggering an Apex Error email, because we are seeing unhandled errors that go under the radar.